ApexMocks throwing System.TypeException: Class IEmailService__sfdc_ApexStub must implement the method
When running a unit test, I get the following error:
System.TypeException: Class IEmailService__sfdc_ApexStub must implement the method: void IEmailService.sendErrorToAdmins(String, Exception)
(System Code)
Class.fflib_ApexMocks.mock: line 67, column 1
Class.MigratePhoneNumbersBatchableTest.execute: line 12, column 1

The relevant unit test code is the following:
@IsTest
private class MigratePhoneNumbersBatchableTest {
    @IsTest
    static void execute() {
        fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();
        IAssetsSelector assetsSelectorMock = (IAssetsSelector) mocks.mock(IAssetsSelector.class);
        IPhoneAccountsSelector phoneAccountsSelectorMock = (IPhoneAccountsSelector) mocks.mock(IPhoneAccountsSelector.class);
        IEmailService emailServiceMock = (IEmailService) mocks.mock(IEmailService.class); // THIS IS LINE 12
        fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork uowMock = (fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork) mocks.mock(fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork.class);
        ...
    }
}

The interface I'm trying to mock is the following:
public interface IEmailService {
    void sendErrorToAdmins(String processName, Exception e);
    void sendErrorToAdmins(String processName, String body, Exception e);
    void sendEmailToAdmins(String subject, String body, Boolean isHtml);
    void sendEmailsToAdminsAsync(List<EmailMessageWrapper> messages);
    Id getTemplateId(String templateName);
    Id getOrgWideEmailAddressId(String orgWideEmailAddressName);
}

In the library project, class fflib_ApexMocks, the failing method is:
/**
 * Creates mock object of given class or interface.
 * @param classToMock class or interface to mock.
 * @return mock object.
 */
public Object mock(Type classToMock)
{
    return Test.createStub(classToMock, this); // THIS IS LINE 67
}

My question is: why doesn't it work? What am I missing?
I guess there are some limitations around the Stub API, but in the docs I couldn't find anything that applies here.
I tried to rename one of the two sendErrorToAdmins methods, to be sure it's not something related to overloading. Nothing changes.
EDIT: I could reproduce the error with this simple unit test:
@IsTest
static void myTest() {
    fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();
    IEmailService emailServiceMock = (IEmailService) mocks.mock(IEmailService.class);
}


The reason is the Exception e as the method parameter. This is not a fflib-apex-mocks limitation, it's generic to Salesforce. I still would love to know why though.
The workaround I thought of is to make an ExceptionWrapper class, and pass it as the parameter if the need is to mock the IEmailService interface. E.g.
public class ExceptionWrapper {
    public final Exception e;

    public ExceptionWrapper(Exception e) {
        this.e = e;
    }
}

public interface IEmailService {
    void sendErrorToAdmins(String processName, ExceptionWrapper e);
    ...
}

The implementation will have to unwrap it. I tested it and it works.
I quite dislike this approach, so I'll be happy to hear about a better one.
